# How to get Date/ Time to work with Data Validation and INDEX(MATCH()) or VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to set up a summary sheet that pulls relevant information based on input from three `Data Validation` drop-downs.

Link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LlOdONYI6hd2U5uVmD4C5i3WpuieOdohxIAnwfudUC8/edit?usp=sharing

I have a `QUERY` in `'Calculations'!E2`, with `Data Validation` in  `'Calculations'!F2` based on the results in `'Calculations'!E2`, then two other `QUERY` in `'Calculations'!G2` and `'Calculations'!I2` with accompanying `Data Validation` in `'Calculations'!H2` and `'Calculations'!J2` respectively.

My first problem is when I get to the `Data Validation` in `'Calculations'!J2`: Regardless of whether the selection looks identical to one of the times displayed in `'Calculations'!C:C`, I always get an "`Input must fall within the specified range`" error.

My second problem: I can't get a formula to work that pulls the information I'm looking for from the "Form Responses" sheet. I've tried an `INDEX(MATCH())` in `'Summary'!A8`, and a `VLOOKUP` in `'Summary'!A10`, but both say they can't find the date from `'Calculations'!J2`.
I've tried adding/ removing significant digits with formatting and `ROUND` functions, but it won't match even though the data should be identical (the number in `'Calculations'!J2` is *literally* pulled directly from the dates in `'Form Responses'!A2:A`, isn't it? Is that the problem?).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve but here : `(MATCH($C$4,'Form Responses'!$A$2:$A,0)` you are trying to match a datetime with a name....

Comment: Is the data in `'Form Responses'!A2:A` considered a name? They are datetimes that are automatically added when a Google Form is completed, and the data in `'Summary'!C4` is actually pulled from the datetimes in `'Form Responses'!A2:A` by way of the `QUERY` formulas that start in `'Calculations'!A2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E2:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:A, "where A is not null", 0))
```

G2:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:C, "select B where A = '"&F2&"'", 0))
```

I2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(N(QUERY(A2:C, "select C where A = '"&F2&"' and B = '"&H2&"'", 0)))
```

K2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(J2, {C2:C, A2:C}, {2, 3, 4}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: YES!! Thank you. The only small edit I made was for K2 in the second set of curly braces:
`ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(J2, {C2:C, A2:C}, {4},0)))` and that worked perfectly!

Out of curiosity, why did you include the "0" at the end of your `QUERY` formulas? Does that make a big difference vs. omitting them?

Comment: in some cases, not including 3rd query parameter may cause undesired results, so... just for safety